# Reading bin file and send content to jni

Tags: java, android, c, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I have to read a binary file in my assets folder and I have to pass file's content to my jni side in order to extract some info with c struct.
On Android side I have to print values, but when app starts it crashes.

Some advice?
Thanks in advance.

JNI C/C++ SIDE

```
        typedef struct struct_APP_CONFIG *ptr_sAPP_CONFIG;
        APP_CONFIG *AppConfig_struct;
        ptr_sAPP_CONFIG  ptr_AppConfig;
        char value;

        int uploadCnfdf(char *ptr_tmpString){

            ptr_AppConfig = (ptr_sAPP_CONFIG) calloc(1, (sizeof(APP_CONFIG)));
            memcpy((void *)ptr_AppConfig,(const void *)ptr_tmpString,sizeof(APP_CONFIG));

            return sizeof(APP_CONFIG);

        }

           JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_test_MainActivity_sendData(JNIEnv* env, jbyteArray data) {

            //COPY ARRAY FROM JAVA
            jbyte *buffer = env->GetByteArrayElements(data, NULL);
            jsize len = env->GetArrayLength(data);
            env->ReleaseByteArrayElements(data, buffer, 0);

            //CONVERT ARRAY TO CHAR
            unsigned char *buf = new unsigned char[len];
            env->GetByteArrayRegion((jbyteArray) buffer, 0, len, reinterpret_cast<jbyte *>(buf));
            //CALL FUNCTION
            uploadCnfdf((char *) buffer);
//SISTEM.MAX is a char type and its value is 5
            value = ptr_AppConfig->setup.setup_map.MEMORY.SETUP.TABLE_SETUP.SISTEM.MAX; 
            }
    jstring
    Java_test_MainActivity_stringFromJNI(
            JNIEnv *env,
            jobject /* this */) {

            return env->NewStringUTF((const char *) value);

    }
```

ANDROID/JAVA SIDE

```
        public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


            static {
                System.loadLibrary("native-lib");
            }

            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
                try {
                    readBin();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                // Example of a call to a native method
                TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sample_text);
                tv.setText(stringFromJNI());
            }


            void readBin() throws IOException {
                AssetManager am = getAssets();
                InputStream file = am.open("file.bin");
                byte [] filebytes = new byte[file.available()];
                //String str = new String(filebytes);
                //String chars = filebytes.toString();
                file.read(filebytes);
                file.close();
try {
            sendData(filebytes);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.getMessage();
        }            }

            public native String stringFromJNI();
            private native void sendData(byte[] data);
        }
```

LOG CAT

```
0-04 15:20:06.163 728-728/java.app_android A/art: art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65] JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: jarray argument has non-array type: java.app_android.MainActivity
10-04 15:20:06.163 728-728/java.app_android A/art: art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]     in call to GetByteArrayElements
10-04 15:20:06.163 728-728/java.app_android A/art: art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]     from void java.app_android.MainActivity.sendData(byte[])
10-04 15:20:06.163 728-728/java.app_android A/art: art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65] "main" prio=5 tid=1 Runnable
10-04 15:20:06.163 728-728/java.app_android A/art: art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x7485f000 self=0xb7ca9800
```

Comment: Show the logcat for crash report.

Comment: `String chars = filebytes.toString();`. You can remove that statement.

Comment: `file.read(filebytes);`. There will be a return value telling you how many bytes are read. Use it.

Comment: `file.available()`. Have you ever checked if that delivers the right size of your file?

Comment: Put the call to sendData() in a try block so your app does not crash.

Comment: `catch (IOException e)`.If you have a catch you should put `e.getMessage()` in that text view. And not continue with your code but return.

Comment: I putted the code in a try catch block but the app crashes again.

Comment: I wait untill i get answer for all my questions.

Comment: Sorry for the waiting...
file.available return 26881 as size
file.read(filebytes) return 26881 as size.

Comment: Ok but what is the size of the file really? You did put a file in assets isnt it?

Comment: 27KB
both the functions returns a value I print that value.

int read = file.read(filebytes);
int size = file.available();
Yes in /src/main/assets/file.bin

Comment: In bytes please. Not in KB. We are checking things arent we?

Comment: Is `Java_test_MainActivity_sendData()` executed if you call `sendData()`. If so then your error message tells you that byte[] is unequal to jbyteArray[]. Or is there somwhere a conversion?

Comment: ls -l output 
-rw-r--r--  1 user  staff  26881  4 Ott 16:16 file.bin

Comment: Please show definition of `jbyteArray`.

Comment: How I have to pass that byte []?

Comment: `Please show definition of jbyteArray.`. Any reason why you didn't? And answer my question!

Comment: JbyteArray is the jni equivalent definition of Java byteArray

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`JNIEnv* env, jbyteArray data` is not a correct argument specification for your C++ function. It will always receive two arguments (plus whatever extra arguments you pass to it): a `JNIEnv*`, and a `jobject`/`jclass` holding a reference to the Java object or class that the native method is being invoked on.

So, `sendData` should be:

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_test_MainActivity_sendData(JNIEnv* env,
                                                       jobject thiz,
                                                       jbyteArray data) {
```

And if it had been declared `static` on the Java side it would've been:

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_test_MainActivity_sendData(JNIEnv* env,
                                                       jclass clazz,
                                                       jbyteArray data) {
```

The log is telling you this in the part `jarray argument has non-array type: java.app_android.MainActivity`.Here it's telling you that `sendData` received a reference to a `MainActivity` instance as its second argument where it was expecting a `jbyteArray` because that was what you had specified.

Comment: adding  "jobject thiz" the app still crash :/

Comment: Well, just saying that it still crashes without giving any details isn't very helpful.

Comment: now it gives this type of error

`--------- beginning of crash
10-04 17:04:57.926 25344-25344/java.app_android A/libc: Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 25344 (java.app_android)
10-04 17:04:58.769 257-257/? E/lowmemorykiller: Error opening /proc/25344/oom_score_adj; errno=2
10-04 17:04:58.796 1208-1624/? E/WindowState: getStack: Window{24336dd9 u0 Starting java.app_android} couldn't find taskId=805 Callers=com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService...`

Comment: Which statement is causing that? Remove code to find out.

Comment: I don't see anything in that log that points to your app. However, you're doing some weird things in your C++ code, like trying to use `buffer` after you've called `ReleaseByteArrayElements`, and trying to cast a `jbyte*` to a `jbyteArray`. You really need to read and understand [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html) for the JNI functions that you use.

Comment: I resolved with a conversion
`int len = env->GetArrayLength(data);
 char* buf = new char[len];
env->GetByteArrayRegion(data,0,len, reinterpret_cast<jbyte*>(buf));
uploadCnfdf(buf);
value = ptr_AppConfig->setup.setup_map.MEMORY.SETUP.TABLE_SETUP.SISTEM.MAX; 
LOGD("VALUE %u",(unsigned)value);`
I really do appreciate all your great advice and helping me.
 Thank you so much.